# How to render items in a list one by one in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ramda.js

I want to render video thumbnails one at a time so that I can improve the performance of my website.

I have tried using a map but the map loops through all items at once and returns a list of components to render

I have also tried using a while loop but the while loop only renders one thumbnail (*the first thumbnail*)

here is my render method

```
render(){
        const { videos } = this.state;
        const listVideos = () => {
            let vids = videos
            let loopedAllVids = false;
            while(!loopedAllVids){
                const head = R.head(vids); // returns first item
                const { thumbnail } = head;
                vids = R.tail(vids); // returns all items but first item
                if(vids.length === 0){
                    loopedAllVids = true;
                }
                return(
                    <div 
                      className='video' 
                      style={{background:`url(${thumbnail})`}}>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
        return(
            <div  className="row text-center">
                <div className="col-md-12 header">
                    <h1> My Youtube Videos </h1>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 videos">
                            {videos.length> 0 && listVideos()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: if you have long list of videos use pagination.

Comment: Your code calls listVideos() function which will list down all the entries present in the state array. 

You will need to add 1 video in the state at a time and then render(list) it.

Do you want to load thumbnail when the user scrolls down?

Let me know your response.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327755/how-to-wait-to-render-view-in-react-js-until-get-is-complete

Comment: the return statement breaks the while loop.

Comment: Thanks guys I found a solution to my problem.  Thanks to @sathishkumar 's comment I found out about using  an infinite scroll technique

Answer (score 1):

The while methods return only one thumbs because the "return" statement stop the while loop and the map method return a new array after iterating the first one.

Anyway i don't think this is the right way to achieve your goal.
I think it will be better to store your thumbs in a component state and to increment it one thumb by one (maybe using the "setTimeout" method).

Another way is to look at an already existing "Lazyload" solution (https://github.com/twobin/react-lazyload for example).

Answer (score 1):

*Others have already explained what's wrong with your `while` loop so I won't cover that again.*

If you wish to render only a subset of a list at a given time, you need to implement a pagination. You can still use [`map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) to render that subset though.

For the pagination, you could use [`slice`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#slice):

```
const videos = [
  {id: 0},
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3},
  {id: 4},
  {id: 5},
  {id: 6},
  {id: 7},
  {id: 8},
  {id: 9}
];

slice(0, 3, videos);  // 0, 1, 2
slice(3, 6, videos);  // 3, 4, 5
slice(6, 9, videos);  // 6, 7, 8
slice(9, 12, videos); // 9
```

I would also (as suggested by others) extract the rendering of videos into a separate function.

Here's a function to render one thumbnail. It accepts a video object but destructure it to take only what it needs:

```
const renderThumbnail = ({thumbnail}) => (
  <div class="video" style={{background: url(`${thumbnail}`)}}></div>
);
```

And here's a function that accepts a list of videos to render:

```
const renderThumbnails = map(renderThumbnail);
```

And this is how you could use it in your `render` function:

```
render() {
  // videoIndex, displayCount: assuming you have implemented pagination somehow
  const { videos, videoIndex, displayCount } = this.state;
  return (
      <div  className="row text-center">
          <div className="col-md-12 header">
              <h1> My Youtube Videos </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 videos">
                      {videos.length > 0 && renderThumbnails(slice(videoIndex, videoIndex + displayCount, videos))}
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement breaks the while loop and you should move the function outside the render function.

```
listVideos = (videos) => {

  let vids = videos
  let loopedAllVids = false;

  const videosToRender = []

  while(!loopedAllVids){

    const head = R.head(vids); // returns first item
    const { thumbnail } = head;

    vids = R.tail(vids); // returns all items but first item

    if(vids.length === 0){
       loopedAllVids = true;
    }

    videosToRender.push(
      <div 
         className='video' 
         style={{background:`url(${thumbnail})`}}>
       </div>
      )
    }

    return videosToRender;
}

render() {

  const { videos } = this.state;
  return(
      <div  className="row text-center">
          <div className="col-md-12 header">
              <h1> My Youtube Videos </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 videos">
                      {videos.length > 0 && this.listVideos(videos)}
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  )

}
```